# What does this orange symbol mean?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Since installing the latest patch, I've started seeing damage numbers with an orange symbol around them. What does this mean?

[image: Image showing orange text]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the new additions in the [2013-04-30 patch](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/news/Game-Update-Notes-April-30-2013), is a visual indicator for [Retaliation](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Retaliation) damage.

> Retaliation now has its own iconic damage floater.

The symbol itself is the Retaliation fist symbol([image]), and it appears around any damage numbers which are caused by Retaliation damage.